# Spring data JPA: cannot persist object with attribute of type Point

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

While trying to persist an object with an attribute of type `Point`, defined as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "POINT")
    private Point coordinate;

}
```

I'm getting the error `Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`.

The corresponding database table is defined as follows:

```sql
create table event
(
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   coordinate POINT,
   primary key (id)
)
engine= InnoDB;
```

The application uses Spring Boot 2.7.3 and talks to a MySQL Server 8.0. In the `application.properties` the database is configured as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect
```

And I've added the following dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here's the full log:

```
2022-09-24 11:21:41.386 DEBUG 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into event (coordinate) values (?)
2022-09-24 11:21:41.395 TRACE 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [Point [x=48.164455, y=7.544595]]
2022-09-24 11:21:41.427  WARN 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1416, SQLState: 22001
2022-09-24 11:21:41.427 ERROR 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
2022-09-24 11:21:41.508 DEBUG 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2022-09-24 11:21:41.572 ERROR 18820 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

What am I missing?

**Edit 1**: the following SQL statement works fine in MySQL Workbench: `INSERT INTO event (coordinate) VALUES (POINT(48.164455, 7.544595));`

Comment: Add this to the jdbc url and check whether work         
 ?stringtype=unspecified

Comment: @YJR thanks, tried that one but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: org.springframework...Point? Try `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point` ...+ https://stackoverflow.com/q/69148815/592355

Comment: @xerx593 yes that works! Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thank you for the "rep"! & very happy could help you, but let's mark it "better" "duplicate"!?;(